# jQuery Ajax can't change checkbox state

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I am trying to change a checkbox state but it does not seems to work.
This is my code:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'includes/exproty.php',
  type: 'post',
  data: {
    'product_id': '100'
  },
  success: function(data) {
    var product_details = JSON.parse(data);
    if (product_details.is_published) {
      console.log("Works");
      $("[name='active']").checked = true;
    } else {
      $("[name='active']").checked = false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="input_container">
  <label>Active</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="active" />
</div>
```

The `console.log` inside the `if` is used in order for me to confirm the condition is met and the code inside the `if` is executed.

I also tried this:

```
$("[name='active']").prop('checked', true);
```

But it does not work either.

I know for certain the condition is met and is executing (thanks to the `console.log`).

If needed any more information, ask for it and I will try to provide it. Thanks!

Comment: Unable to reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/czq3pbhj/4/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because jQuery objects have no `checked` property. That belongs to native Element objects. For jQuery, you should be using `prop()` instead.

If that is not working for you, then you either have an error in the AJAX logic, which you should check the console to diagnose, or you have multiple elements with the `name="active"` attribute, in which case you should use a different selector.

Also note that you don't need to call `JSON.parse()` manually. jQuery will automatically deserialise the response for you, so `data` will already be an object. Deserialising it again will cause an error. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'includes/exproty.php',
  type: 'post',
  data: { product_id: '100' }, // consider changing this value to an int
  dataType: 'json', // explicitly set return data type
  success: function(data) {
    $("[name='active']").prop('checked', product_details.is_published);
  }
});
```

Comment: I can assure you at absolutely works when used correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/h2jz8koL/. If you have issues, check the console for errors, and ensure you have only one element with the `name="active"` attribute

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the parsing but it still does not work...
I have only one element with that name and no errors in console

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Unfortunately simply stating 'it doesn't work' doesn't give us any useful information to help diagnose the issue you have

Comment: Add this line before the if statement.  Maybe the data is not returning what you think it is. console.log("is_published: "+product_details.is_published);

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I know simply saying "does not work" is not enough but I do not what else to provide, I can't see any console error, and the code is fine, as far as I know.. That is why I said if there is any more information needed, tell me and I'll provide it.

Comment: @jeffld This is the output I am getting: `is_published: 1` which is also what I'm suppose to get

Comment: Try what @jeffld suggested, and also `console.log(data)` within the `success` handler

Comment: so it is 1 not true?

Comment: Right but in the `if` the condition evaluates to `true` and is getting executed but the checkbox does not change...

Answer (score 0):

Please try the jquery attr

```
if (product_details.is_published) {
     console.log("Works");
     $("[name='active']").attr({'checked':'checked'});
} else {
     $("[name='active']").attr({'checked':''});
}
```

Comment: Firstly, `prop()` is better practice. Secondly, if `prop()` doesn't work, then this won't either. There must be another underlying problem

Comment: Just FYI you don't need to pass an object to the `.attr()` function if you're only changing a single attribute - you can use `$("[name='active']").attr("checked", "checked")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using jquery 1.6 or higher.
Try this..
using checkbox id:
`$(window).find("#checkboxid").prop("checked", true);`

or using checkbox class (This will be applied for all the class used tags)

`$(window).find(".classname").prop("checked", true);`

Answer (score 0):

Try following, tested - should work:

```
$("input[name='active']").attr( "checked", true);
$("input[name='active']").attr( "checked", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.prop('checked', true)`. It is jQuery speciffic and include  `is_published` in `data: {'product_id': '100',}`.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'includes/exproty.php',
  type: 'post',
  data: {
    'product_id': '100',
    'product_details' : is_published
  },
  success: function(data) {
    var product_details = JSON.parse(data);
    if (product_details.is_published) {
      console.log("Works");
      $("[name='active']").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $("[name='active']").prop('checked', false);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_container">
  <label>Active</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="active" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried to manually refresh the label after the update of the prop value. I wrote the following:

```
$('#CheckBoxID').prop('checked', true);

$('label[for="CheckBoxID"]').addClass('ui-checkbox-on');
$('label[for="CheckBoxID"]').removeClass('ui-checkbox-off')
```